# Issue with Homebrew install on Mac

Tags: macos, bash, homebrew

As prescribed by the Homebrew installation guide I input the following into the terminal:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

What it spits back is the following:

```
-e:4: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<!DOCTYPE html>
 ^
-e:5: syntax error, unexpected '<'
<html>
 ^
-e:7: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
     ^
-e:8: syntax error, unexpected '<'
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     ^
-e:8: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

At that point, running any brew command spits back the following:

```
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Any thoughts on a solution? Thanks.

Comment: Where did you find those instructions? It appears to be a URL present in older revisions of the installation page, but not recently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The provided URL doesn't work for me either, but this does:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

I suspect something changed on GitHub's end.

Comment: Perfect, problem solved! Thanks James. And "thanks" GitHub. :|

Comment: This has not resolved it for me. I have installed xcode, xcode tools, xcode terminal tools (latest versions) I am have tried sudo too.